# Beautiful Soup: can't get the text (price) out of this

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

[
How can I get the price out of this mess.]

```
<li class="price-current">
               <span class="price-current-label">
               </span>₹ 36,659 <a class="price-current-num" href="https://www.newegg.com/global/in-en/gigabyte-geforce-rtx-2070-super-gv-n207swf3oc-8gd/p/N82E16814932213?Item=N82E16814932213&amp;buyingoptions=New">(3 Offers)</a>
               <span class="price-current-range">
               <abbr title="to">–</abbr>
               </span>
 </li>
```

[image]

Comment: Please, don't post HTML code as image. Edit your question and put it there as text. That way we can copy it and try to find a solution.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for the advice.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python get field from HTML", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  We expect you to do basic searches before posting here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.find_next_sibling()` with `text=True` parameter to locate the price:

```
data = '''<li class="price-current">
               <span class="price-current-label">
               </span>₹ 36,659 <a class="price-current-num" href="https://www.newegg.com/global/in-en/gigabyte-geforce-rtx-2070-super-gv-n207swf3oc-8gd/p/N82E16814932213?Item=N82E16814932213&amp;buyingoptions=New">(3 Offers)</a>
               <span class="price-current-range">
               <abbr title="to">–</abbr>
               </span>
 </li>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('.price-current-label').find_next_sibling(text=True))
```

Prints:

```
₹ 36,659
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate that.